How does nginx clears memory in limiting requests
In this link I see the nginx says:

Zone – Defines the shared memory zone used to store the state of each IP address and how often it has accessed a request‑limited URL. Keeping the information in shared memory means it can be shared among the NGINX worker processes. The definition has two parts: the zone name identified by the zone= keyword, and the size following the colon. State information for about 16,000 IP addresses takes 1 ;megabyte, so our zone can store about 160,000 addresses.

My questions and what I don't understand are the following:

How long it takes for nginx to clear the memory of stored IP addresses?

In this part, it says:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:10m rate=10r/s;

The 10m by the previous definition, it means 1,600,000 IP addresses.

For how long the nginx stores these IP addresses and how it clears them?

The purpose of this question is this:
I set a rate limit like this:
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=mylimit:1m rate=2r/s;

I create a very simple html page which has one request only. So technically I can refresh this page 2 times per second and for the 3rd time to refresh, I should be faced with an error like 503 or 429.
Up to this point, everything is fine. But after a couple of seconds 15 seconds waiting and doing nothing, I refresh the page but I still get 503 or 429 error.
I even did systemctl reload nginx but I still see error page. Then I did systemctl restart nginx but nothing changed.
Am I doing anything wrong here? Did I misunderstood anything here? Or there are some topics or subjects I don't know?
Update
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=front_limit:100m rate=50r/s;
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=saeed:1m rate=1r/s;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        root /var/www/html/;
        index index.html;
        try_files /$uri /$uri/ /index.html;
        limit_req zone=front_limit burst=50 delay=50;
        limit_req_status 429;
        error_page 429 /home/custom_429.html;
    }
    location /saeed.html {
        root /home/;
        limit_req zone=saeed;
        limit_req_status 500;
    }
}

I also see this errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log:
2024/05/16 22:16:57 [error] 16531#16531: *4866 limiting requests, excess: 0.500 by zone "saeed", client: my_ip_v4, server: example.com, request: "GET /saeed.html HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com"


Do you use nginx as a reverse proxy? Can you post your full nginx config?

@Marc I don't use nginx as reverse proxy. I have a backend too, but at this moment I'm testing the rate limit for the frontend which is served static. I tried to edit the question but the button to save edits is not enable:( Not sure about it.

@Marc I edited the question and added nginx config.

Can reproduce. After restarting nginx, the reate limit is cleared, and the pages can be access again. Tested on 22.04.4 LTS with nginx v1.18.0.

@Marc yes you're right. It seems I had some other misconfiguration. But regarding other questions, can you help?
